# Как правильно разобрать JSON объект без заголовков

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Получаю ответ сервера вот в таком виде:

```
suggest.apply(["Сам",[["geo","Самара, Россия","Россия, Самара ",{"hl":[[0,3]]}],["geo","Самарская область, Россия","Россия, Самарская область ",{"hl":[[0,3]]}],["geo","Самаркандский бульвар, Москва, Россия","Россия, Москва, Самаркандский бульвар ",{"hl":[[0,3]]}],["geo","улица Самуила Маршака, поселение Внуковское, Москва, Россия","Россия, Москва, поселение Внуковское, улица Самуила Маршака ",{"hl":[[6,9]]}],["geo","Самарканд, Самаркандская область, Узбекистан","Узбекистан, Самаркандская область, Самарканд ",{"hl":[[0,3],[11,14]]}],["geo","Садовая-Самотёчная улица, Москва, Россия","Россия, Москва, Садовая-Самотёчная улица ",{"hl":[[0,18,"mp"]]}],["geo","улица Саморы Машела, Москва, Россия","Россия, Москва, улица Саморы Машела ",{"hl":[[6,9]]}]]])
```

Проблема в том, что он обернут в `suggest.apply()` и у него нет заголовков. Не могу понять как к нему подступиться.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как его правильнее будет разобрать? Желательно с использованием библиотеки **Retrofit**.

Answer (score 1):

Для очистки ответа сервера в Retrofit используется пользовательский конвертер.
Хороший пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290267/retrofit-removing-some-invalid-characters-from-response-body-before-parsing-it
И еще немного примеров: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter.
Надеюсь поможет :)